# Transpose rows to columns without aggragation

Tags: sql, pivot

I want to transpose rows to columns against RuleID and Dname.Following is sample data. Please help me out to acheive it

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
[RuleID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[DateTime1] [datetime] NULL,
[DName] [nvarchar](30) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].Table1 ([RuleID], [DateTime1], [DName]) VALUES (N'DBRS', CAST(N'2017-03-28T12:22:04.000' AS DateTime), N'DB1')
INSERT [dbo].Table1 ([RuleID], [DateTime1], [DName]) VALUES (N'DBRK', CAST(N'2017-03-28T12:22:04.260' AS DateTime), N'DB1')
INSERT [dbo].Table1 ([RuleID], [DateTime1], [DName]) VALUES (N'DBRE', CAST(N'2017-03-28T12:22:09.000' AS DateTime), N'DB1')
INSERT [dbo].Table1 ([RuleID], [DateTime1], [DName]) VALUES (N'DBRK', CAST(N'2017-04-04T08:33:15.870' AS DateTime), N'DB2')
INSERT [dbo].Table1 ([RuleID], [DateTime1], [DName]) VALUES (N'DBRE', CAST(N'2017-04-04T08:33:31.000' AS DateTime), N'DB2')
INSERT [dbo].Table1 ([RuleID], [DateTime1], [DName]) VALUES (N'DBRK', CAST(N'2017-04-04T09:14:30.503' AS DateTime), N'DB2')
INSERT [dbo].Table1 ([RuleID], [DateTime1], [DName]) VALUES (N'DBRS', CAST(N'2017-04-04T09:14:31.000' AS DateTime), N'DB2')
INSERT [dbo].Table1 ([RuleID], [DateTime1], [DName]) VALUES (N'DBRE', CAST(N'2017-04-04T09:44:33.000' AS DateTime), N'DB2')
```

Desired Output:

```
SELECT 'DB1' As DName,'2017-03-28 12:22:04.260'AS BRKIndicated ,'2017-03-28 12:22:04.000' As BRKStart,'2017-03-28 12:22:09.000' AS BRKEnd
UNION
SELECT 'DB2'As DName,'2017-04-04 08:33:15.870'AS BRKIndicated,NULL As BRKStart,'2017-04-04 08:33:31.000'AS BRKEnd
UNION
SELECT 'DB2'As DName,'2017-04-04 09:14:30.503'AS BRKIndicated,'2017-04-04 09:14:31.000' As BRKStart,'2017-04-04 09:44:33.000'AS BRKEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PIVOT table :

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM Table1
) A 
PIVOT
(
  MAX(DateTime1) FOR RuleID IN ([DBRS],[DBRK],[DBRE])
)pvt
```

Comment: I will miss second row if I use Max(DateTime1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a self join

```
select D1.DName, D1.DateTime1 as DBRS, D2.DateTime1 as DBRK, D3.DateTime1 as DBRE
from Table1 D1
inner join Table1 D2
  on D1.DName = D2.DName
  and D2.RuleID = 'DBRK'
inner join Table1 D3
  on D1.DName = D3.DName
  and D3.RuleID = 'DBRE'
where D1.RuleID = 'DBRS'
```

If it's possible that one of the values might be missing, use `LEFT JOIN` instead

Comment: This gives me duplicates

Comment: @user2545157 There are duplicates in your data... How can you determine which row each of the 'DB2' items belongs in?

Comment: DBRK is break indicated,DBRS is Breakstart,DBRE is BreakEnd.. all this make one set against each Dname.. if any of them is missing then it should be updated as null..

Comment: Check your sample data, it does not match your expected output. If there are more criteria, apply them to the join, but this is the solution you need.